# How do I add regex to @Pattern annotation to match one of two specific strings or a null?

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, kotlin, validation

I've added @Pattern annotation to a query parameter in my rest controller (SpringBoot Kotlin). I would like the regex in the pattern to accept -

optionA or optionB or null (nothing/an empty string)

The following works, but of course does not include the empty option -

```
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?i)optionA||(?i)optionB")
```

This does not work -

```
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?i)optionA||(?i)optionB||^\\s*\$")
```

Can anybody help me with this? :)
Thanks!

Comment: Does `@Pattern(regexp = "(?i)(?:optionA)?")` work?

Comment: It does indeed! And (?i)(?:optionA)?||(?i)(?:optionB)? works too. I just need to figure out how to allow a null/empty string

Comment: `(?i)(?:optionA)?` does allow an empty string. `null` is a memory address, not a string, it cannot be matched with regex, as regex only deals with strings.

Comment: Use only one (consecutive) `|` in a regular expression.  `||` is for Java boolean expressions, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `@Pattern` annotation, the pattern is used to match the entire string, so you can use

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(?i)(?:optionA)?")
```

which is actually `\A(?i)(?:optionA)?\z`:

- `\A` - start of string (implicit here)
- `(?i)` - case insensitive embedded flag option
- `(?:optionA)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches `optionA` or empty string
- `\z` - end of string (implicit here).

The `null` is a memory address, not a string, it cannot be matched with regex, as regex only deals with strings.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this optionA|optionB|^\s$ on https://regex101.com/ and worked well. Could you try on your app to check?

Comment: I tried that inside the @Pattern annotation and it didn't work there :(, that said it does work on the regex matched site you have.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).